# Use user's args to create an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command that passes the args given by the message author in an embed.

This is the code

```js
        const args = message.content.split(", ");

        var titleargs = args[1]
        var descriptionargs = args[2]
        var footerargs = args[3]
        {
          {
              var myInfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(titleargs)
                  .setDescription(descriptionargs)
                  .setFooter(footerargs)
                  .setColor(0xff0000)
  
  
                  message.channel.send(myInfo);
  
          }
      }
```

This code works, but I don't want to put the first ", " after the prefix and the command

[image]

What should I change?

EDIT: I'm using command handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the prefix and the command from the string and then split by `,`. Check the following snippet:

```js
const prefix = '&'
const command = 'announce'
const message = {
  content: '&announce a 1, b 2, c 3'
}

const args = message.content
  // remove the prefix and the command
  .slice(prefix.length + command.length)
  .split(',')
  // remove extra whitespaces
  .map(s => s.trim())

console.log(args)
```

You could also destructure the `title`, `description`, and `footer` args:

```js
const args = message.content
  .slice(prefix.length + command.length)
  .split(',')
  .map((s) => s.trim())

const [title, description, footer] = args

const myInfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(title)
  .setDescription(description)
  .setFooter(footer)
  .setColor(0xff0000)

message.channel.send(myInfo)
```

[image]

Comment: It outputs "ReferenceError: command is not defined"

Comment: Well, if `command` is undefined... `command` is the word "announce", so you can add `const command = 'announce'`.